# Formatting a tag is not working with Thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

Why does this piece of code display the image before the text:

```
<p>
  <span>
    <img src="../assets/images/favorite.svg" height="12px"/>
  </span>
  Baked Alaskan Salmon with Asparagus
</p>
```

But when formatted with Thymeleaf it does not display the image:

```
<p th:text="@{' ' + ${recipe.name}}">
  <span>
    <img src="../assets/images/favorite.svg" height="12px"/>
  </span>
  Baked Alaskan Salmon with Asparagus
</p>
```

Comment: `height="12px"` is wrong. img height/width cannot use css measurements. they accept pixel values only, as a plain integer.

Comment: strange, but first code with same height="12px" attribute works perfect. Only difference between is Plain text and Thymeleaf pattern

Comment: probably because your browser is being "polite" and chopping off the px, but it doesn't change the fact that the attribute value is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Thymleaf's` `th:inline="text"` tag to display html content inside of `Thymleaf` processed tags.
Following code should work, i have not tested it though

```
<p th:inline="text">
    [[@{' ' + ${recipe.name}}]]
    <span>
        <img src="../assets/images/favorite.svg" style="height:12px"/>
    </span>
    Baked Alaskan Salmon with Asparagus
</p>
```

For more description on how `inline` tag works check out the [docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#text-inlining)

Comment: What does it say? The error? Open the console in the browser and see if the img tag is there..There is also a possibility that your img doesnt exist at that path.

Comment: It works! My mistake forgot delete th:text from there :) Thanks!